# Editing items in Sharepoint 2013 with Infopath 2013 form

Tags: 2013, list

I have a form made in Infopath 2013, which send's data to a list on Sharepoint 2013.

If I want to edit any of the items in the list, I have to add the column **"Name (linked with document with editing menu)"**

The regular **"Edit (linked with edit item)"** doesn't work for actually editing the form, only for editing the name, which I assume is because it is an infopath form.

So what I'm asking is, if there is another way to create an editing button or the like, which doesn't use a much space, as a long file name.

Any and all help is greatly appriciated :)